# cannot resolve Preferences.readString method in following code :

Tags: android

package com.jiit.minorproject.emergencycontact;

```
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
/*
 * HOSPITAL, POLICE, FIRESTATION, and AMBULANCE are constant variables that are assigned
 * to their respective emergency itent. It helps us to draw icons and perform web services
 * related activities.
 */
private static final int HOSPITAL = 1;
private static final int POLICE = 2;
private static final int FIRESTATION = 3;
private static final int AMBULANCE = 4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(Preferences.readString(this, Preferences.NAME) == null){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Registration.class));
        if(Preferences.readString(this, Preferences.NAME) == null){
            this.finish();
        }
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

cannot resolve Prefernces.readString method

Comment: Did you even try anything to overcome this error? Simply reading the documentation of the API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) would have been enough information to know that the function you're trying to call does not even exist

Comment: [Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) doesn't have a static `readString` method. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

java.util.prefs.Preferences isn't generally used in Android code.  But even if it was-  there is no readString method in that class.  Look at the docs on it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

I'm not sure why you think that function should exist, but it really doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

How to create an activity PREFERENCE Android?

First create a new XML

[image]

Then This xml say how daughter of MainActivity

[image]

and you see like this

[image]
<sub>(source: [hermosaprogramacion.com](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/android-studio-settings-preconfigured.png))</sub>

it's the first and then play jeje , reed the official information.

[Android developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html): Settings